# How do I ensure a laptop doesn't have any sort of bug or tracking device?

Tags: bios, virus, malware, firmware

Someone recently gifted a laptop to a friend of mine. Without going into details, the friend is suspicious of malware / bug / tracking, but it is a very nice laptop and they would like to keep it.

How do I ensure there is no malware / bug / tracking on it, either in hardware or software?

Certainly I'm going to wipe the OS and replace it with Linux for a start, take it apart to make sure there is nothing soldered onto the motherboard, and flash the BIOS.

Could there be malicious firmware or hardware in other places though? If so, how and where? Could the built in webcam have malicious firmware flashed to it? If so, what is the risk? What firmware could it be running, and how would a bad actor install firmware to the camera? Could the wifi card be running malicious firmware? etc?

Also, let's assume that the BIOS is somehow malware. Is it possible that this malicious BIOS can detect my attempt to flash a known good BIOS and inject itself into the binary for the known good BIOS during the flash attempt?

I seem to recall physical BIOS flashers from 20 years ago, but of course the BIOS chip is soldered onto the motherboard these days.

What is the best reasonable effort I can make to ensure the system is safe to use? I realize this might be a paranoid sounding question, but I am interested to learn exactly what can go wrong if a bad actor has access to a system.

Comment: Make and specific model of laptop?

Comment: If the NSA or Mossad wanted to plant something in the hardware, you will never know. Period. Otherwise, format and reinstall the os.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best reasonable effort I can make to ensure the system is safe to use?

If it's a relatively new one, just sell it. Put a bit of your (your friend's) money to it and buy a new one of the same type.

Finally it'll still be better for you than inspecting each single element.

Comment: The problem with this though is that my friend would end up purchasing a new laptop, and if you sell then buy you end up with something worth a small fraction of what you started with.

Comment: Unless you're an IT security expert (which case you probably wouldn't have asked this question) whatever you do, you can never be completely sure you've checked everything. If you take the computer to an expert it'll surely cost more than just replacing it to one which you trust.